# MCAST_JOIN_GROUP returns not supported

Tags: php, multicast, multicastsocket

I am trying to do udp multicast with php.

But when I try to join the multicast group with:

```
socket_set_option($ttl_socket, SOL_SOCKET, MCAST_JOIN_GROUP, array("group"=>"239.255.24.7","interface"=>"eth0"));
```

It returns:

```
socket_set_option(): unable to set socket option [95]: Operation not supported
```

According the the manual it should be supported since version 5.4. 
I am running version 5.4.45.